# UITableView: How to change the background of overlapped cells when Drag cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell, drag

[image: iPhone Reminder App. screenshot]

I have attached a image.

This is the iPhone's default reminder app.
Like this, I want to make a gray background when the **drag** cell overlap.

Here is what I tried: ;But it looks ugly in the emulator.

```swift
    var beforeTouch: IndexPath?

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
     targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath,
     toProposedIndexPath proposedDestinationIndexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath {

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: proposedDestinationIndexPath) {
            if (self.beforeTouch != sourceIndexPath)
                    && (sourceIndexPath != proposedDestinationIndexPath) {
                if self.beforeTouch == nil {
                    cell.setSelected(true, animated: false)
                } else {
                    cell.setSelected(true, animated: false)
                    tableView.cellForRow(at: beforeTouch!)?.setSelected(false, animated: false)
                }
            }
            self.beforeTouch = proposedDestinationIndexPath
        }
        
        return proposedDestinationIndexPath
    }
```

In this code, I used below method.

**func tableView(_:, targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAt:, toProposedIndexPath:) -> IndexPath**

It seems executed every time when drag and can trace the cell by using the IndexPath of the parameter.

Also, I think there will be a performance problem because the 'cell.setSelected()' is used in a tableView function that is continuously called while dragging. I also have the problem of having to store the indexPath of the previous cell in the storage property of the class, so I am looking for another way.

I think there will be a traditional way to this issue.

Can someone help on how I can achieve it?

[image: current version]